# Powershell copy a file or get the content without lock it

Tags: powershell

We have some scheduled scripts. They have to access a file "Functions.ps1" with dot sourced functions. This "Functions.ps1" is located on a share. Because the ExecutionPolicy I can't load the file like this:

```
. \\share\folder\Functions.ps1
```

The scheduled script must do a copy to the local C:\ and load the file:

```
$str_ScriptPath = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\$(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 100000)_Functions.ps1"
Copy-Item -Path "$str_Share\Functions.ps1" -Destination $str_ScriptPath -Force   
. $str_ScriptPath
Remove-Item -Path $str_ScriptPath
```

The problem is that some scripts are scheduled at the same time.
In this case it occures an error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\88658_Functions.ps1' because it is being used by another process. 
At line:46 char:14
+     Copy-Item <<<<  -Path "$str_Share\Functions.ps1" -Destination $str_ScriptPath -Force
```

I don't see the reason why the error tells the local file is locked. It should be an unique file name and the file does not exist.
I think because the Copy-Item the source ($str_Share\Functions.ps1) is locked. 
My question:
1) Is there a better way to handle this?
2) Or is there a workarround?

Thanks for help
Patrick

Comment: unless your functions on the share reference a .NET library or a dll you should be able to load them from the share...also why remove the functions.ps1 once it is copied.?

Comment: I remove the local one because this should be only used once. If there is a newer version.

Comment: personally i use modules instead of functions based on the link here here....`https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/corporate-powershell-module-repository-part-1-design-and-infrastructure/`

Comment: Thank you for the url. I test this also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to obtain a non-exclusive read-only handle to the file with `[System.IO.File]::Open()`:

```
function Copy-ReadOnly
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Destination
    )

    # Instantiate a buffer for the copy operation
    $Buffer = New-Object 'byte[]' 1024

    # Create a FileStream from the source path, make sure you open it in "Read" FileShare mode
    $SourceFile = [System.IO.File]::Open($Path,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read,[System.IO.FileShare]::Read)
    # Create the new file
    $DestinationFile = [System.IO.File]::Open($Destination,[System.IO.FileMode]::CreateNew)

    try{
        # Copy the contents of the source file to the destination
        while(($readLength = $SourceFile.Read($Buffer,0,$Buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
        {
            $DestinationFile.Write($Buffer,0,$readLength)
        }
    }
    catch{
        throw $_
    }
    finally{
        $SourceFile.Close()
        $DestinationFile.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. I try this solution in the next day and giv a feedback :-)

Comment: @Patrick So, how did it go?

Comment: @Dennis He accepted the answer, so, presumably it went well :)

Comment: @Dennis I'm sorry, it was too long ago - I think I used the function above, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, probably :)