# How can I copy a file in Powershell without locking the source file which is being copied?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to use the "Copy" command in Powershell to copy a source file to a destination folder but not lock the actual file being copied?

Reason for asking is the file being copied is also an input file for a separate process and if the process starts while the Powershell script is running then it will fail if the Powershell script has locked the input file it uses.

Comment: If you're using *Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS)* aka 'Previous Versions', you can mount the latest shadow copy and copy the file from that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell copy a file or get the content without lock it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627593/powershell-copy-a-file-or-get-the-content-without-lock-it)